# mssql freetext / contains equivalent to LIKE '%blog%'

Tags: sql-server

I used to use a LIKE query:

```
WHERE content LIKE '%blog%'
```

Now I try to replace it with mssql full text search:

```
WHERE contains(content, 'blog')
```

However they do not return the same results.

The first one also returns text containing Blogger.
The second one does not. How can I use full text search to produce the same resultset that I get from `LIKE '%...%'`?

Comment: @Tanner - the linked question is dealing with prefix searches. The `LIKE` here is performing a substring search. Admittedly, their *example* is one where the substring is a prefix, but if they really want substring search, they're not getting it from that Q&A.

Comment: @Tanner, I disagree, actually. That question doesn't address the difference in case sensitivity, but mostly discusses stopwords.

Answer (score 0):

Full text search [matches complete words](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/query-with-full-text-search). The LIKE operator can match partial words.

Answer (score 0):

The first one returns blogger because you have used % either side of the word. This returns any data with the word blog in it at any point.

Really you would want to use

```
    WHERE content = 'blog'
```

This would match to the exact word blog.

Comment: That does not match what the OP is asking for. They want to return any test that contains blog, not the exact word.

Comment: But he was asking for the reason as to why he was returning results with 'blogger' - that is the reason

Answer (score 0):

You have three options.

**Option 1:** Just use a trailing wildcard:

```
WHERE CONTAINS(content, '"blog*"')
```

**Option 2:** Use [FREETEXT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/freetext-transact-sql) instead of `CONTAINS`. `FREETEXT` adds inflectional forms of a word to the search, which is probably what you want here.

```
WHERE FREETEXT(content, 'blog')
```

**Option 3:** Extend [CONTAINS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql). This is a bit trickier though. E.g.:

```
WHERE CONTAINS(content, 'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, blog)')
```